# Installing Groovy Mac OSX (10.6.8) using macports

Tags: groovy, macports

When I use the command "sudo port install groovy" from terminal, I get the following error.

```
MyMachine:~ himalay$ sudo port install groovy
--->  Computing dependencies for groovy
--->  Building groovy
Error: org.macports.build for port groovy returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port groovy for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port groovy failed
```

I did run "sudo port -v selfupdate" ,  that dint work either. Here is a log snippet from **main.log**

```
version:1
:debug:main Found Dependency: path: /usr/bin filename: unzip regex: ^unzip$
:msg:main --->  Computing dependencies for groovy:info:main .:debug:main groovy has no conflicts
:debug:main Found Dependency: path: /usr/bin filename: unzip regex: ^unzip$
:debug:main Searching for dependency: unzip
:debug:main Didn't find receipt, going to depspec regex for: unzip
:debug:main Found Dependency: path: /usr/bin filename: unzip regex: ^unzip$
:msg:main 
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (groovy)
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 502
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (groovy)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (groovy)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (groovy)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.extract (groovy)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.patch (groovy)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.configure (groovy)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:build build phase started at Sat May 19 09:25:19 EDT 2012
:notice:build --->  Building groovy
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (groovy)
:debug:build Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.6'
:debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6" && ant install -DskipTests=true'
:debug:build Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6" && ant install -DskipTests=true 
:info:build Buildfile: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6/build.xml
:info:build Trying to override old definition of task javac
:info:build 
:info:build -excludeLegacyAntVersion:
:info:build 
:info:build -checkAntVersion:
:info:build 
:info:build -banner:
:info:build      [echo] Java Runtime Environment version: 1.6.0_31
:info:build      [echo] Java Runtime Environment vendor: Apple Inc.
:info:build      [echo] Ant version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on November 19 2011
:info:build      [echo] Operating system name: Mac OS X
:info:build      [echo] Operating system architecture: x86_64
:info:build      [echo] Operating system version: 10.6.8
:info:build      [echo] Base directory: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6
:info:build      [echo] Java Home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
:info:build 
:info:build -initializeReports:
:info:build 
:info:build -mavenTaskdef:
:info:build 
:info:build -mavenPomDefinitions:
:info:build 
:info:build -mavenInit:
:info:build 
:info:build -mavenFetchAllModules:
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'antlr:antlr:pom:2.7.7:compile' is invalid.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] 
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'asm:asm:pom:3.2:compile' is invalid.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] 
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'junit:junit:pom:4.10:compile' is invalid.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] 
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'commons-cli:commons-cli:pom:1.2:compile' is invalid.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] 
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] POM for 'org.apache.ant:ant:pom:1.8.2:compile' is invalid.
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] 
:info:build [artifact:dependencies] Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.

---
---
---

---
---

:info:build -jvm14BuildWarning:
:info:build 
:info:build stagedcompile:
:info:build     [javac] Compiling 835 source files to /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6/target/classes
:info:build     [javac] error: error reading /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6/target/lib/compile/ant-1.8.2.jar; cannot read zip file
:info:build     [javac] /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6/src/main/groovy/beans/BindableASTTransformation.java:35: package org.objectweb.asm does not exist
:info:build     [javac] import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
:info:build     [javac]                         ^
:info:build     [javac] /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_www.macports.org_files_ports_java_groovy/groovy/work/groovy-1.8.6/src/main/groovy/beans/BindableASTTransformation.java:58: cannot find symbol
```

....
....
....

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use ports? IMO Java stuff is much easier to deal with downloading manually, installing in a versioned directory, and leaving it at that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**sudo port install groovy** did not work for me at all, I used the following.

```
1. Download groovy from http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download
2. Unpack and move to /usr/share'
   ◦$ sudo mv ~/Downloads/groovy-1.8.6 /usr/share/
3. Change ownership and permissions
   ◦$cd /usr/share
   ◦$sudo chown -R root:wheel groovy-1.8.6
   ◦$sudo chmod 0755 groovy-1.8.6/bin/*
4. Create symlink 
   ◦$sudo ln -s groovy-1.8.6 groovy
5. Add GROOVY_HOME and change PATH (in /etc/profile or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile)
   ◦export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/share/groovy
   ◦PATH=$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
6. Test Installation : 
   ◦groovyConsole : Creates an interactive groovy shell where you can type Groovy statements
   ◦groovysh : Swing interactive console
```

Comment: Between step 5 and 6, remember to run the profile file ". ~/.profile" or ". ~/.bash_profile" :)